# Kubernetes Kube-proxy failed to retrieve node info

Tags: kubernetes, kube-dns, kubelet

Trying to understand why I'm seeing this output from my kube-proxy logs

```
W0328 08:00:53.755379  1 server.go:468] Failed to retrieve node info: nodes "ip-172-31-55-175" not found
W0328 08:00:53.755505  1 proxier.go:249] invalid nodeIP, initialize kube-proxy with 127.0.0.1 as nodeIP
```

The cluster is working just fine, is that indicating an issue with the cluster configuration?

Comment: Looks like a warning. Does this occur every time kube-proxy starts on the node?

Comment: How did you setup cluster? If you used kubeadm, you need specify the advertise addr or check your kubelete attributes that you specify your listen addr. It sometime happens when you have multiple eth interfaces.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Can you please show the output of the command `kubectl get node`?

Probably the registered name used when kubelet starts is different from the name that kube-proxy is using.

You can force the usage of this very same name starting kube-proxy with the `--hostname-override` directive, and point to the same name kubelet registered itself.

Comment: thanks Ricardo Katz. override hostname was set wrongly

Comment: Even if the --hostname-override's match on the kubelet and kube-proxy, you might see this if the kubelet was started after the kube-proxy.  Restart kube-proxy to see if starts without complaining about invalid nodeIP.

Comment: --hostname-override didn't work for me, you're supposed to use `--config=` starting k8s 1.10, in the config file you can include `hostnameOverride`, see https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/proxy/apis/kubeproxyconfig/v1alpha1/types.go#L119

Answer (score 1):

For newcomers start the minions(nodes) services in this order.
1. kubelet
2. kube-proxy
3. docker

Incorrect follow ups can trip up the service registrations.