# Kube-proxy fails to retrieve node info - invalid nodeIP

Tags: kubernetes, coreos, kubectl, kube-proxy

I've been trying to setup a Kubernetes cluster for a few months now, but I have no luck so far.

I'm trying to set it up on 4 **bare metal** PCs running **coreOS**. I've just clean installed everything again, but I get to the same problem as before. I'm following [this](https://coreos.com/kubernetes/docs/latest/getting-started.html) tutorial. I think I've configured everything correctly, but am not 100% sure. When I reboot any of the machines, kubelet and flanneld services are running, but I see the following errors for them when checking service status with `systemctl status`:

**kubelet error:** `Process: 1246 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/rkt rm --uuid-file=/var/run/kubelet-pod.uuid (code=exited, status=254)`

**flanneld error**: `Process: 1057 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/rkt rm --uuid-file=/var/lib/coreos/flannel-wrapper.uuid (code=exited, status=254)`

If I restart both services, they work, or at least look like they work - I get no errors.

Everything else seems to work fine, so the only problem (I think) left are the kube-proxy service on all nodes.

If I run `kubectl get pods` I see all pods running:

```
$ kubectl get pods
NAME                                   READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
kube-apiserver-kubernetes-4            1/1       Running   4          6m
kube-controller-manager-kubernetes-4   1/1       Running   6          6m
kube-proxy-kubernetes-1                1/1       Running   4          18h
kube-proxy-kubernetes-2                1/1       Running   5          26m
kube-proxy-kubernetes-3                1/1       Running   4          19m
kube-proxy-kubernetes-4                1/1       Running   4          18h
kube-scheduler-kubernetes-4            1/1       Running   6          18h
```

[The answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43286091/kubernetes-kube-proxy-failed-to-retrieve-node-info) suggest to check if `kubectl get node` returns same names that are registered on kubelet. As far as I checked the logs, nodes are registered correctly, and this is the output of `kubectl get node`

```
$ kubectl get node
NAME           STATUS                        AGE       VERSION
kubernetes-1   Ready                         18h       v1.6.1+coreos.0
kubernetes-2   Ready                         36m       v1.6.1+coreos.0
kubernetes-3   Ready                         29m       v1.6.1+coreos.0
kubernetes-4   Ready,SchedulingDisabled      18h       v1.6.1+coreos.0
```

The tutorial I've used (linked above) suggest I use `--hostname-override` but I couldn't get node info on master node (kubernetes-4) If i tried to curl it locally. So I removed it and I can get node info normally now.

Someone suggested it might be a flannel problem and that I should check the flannel ports. Using `netstat -lntu` I get the following output:

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:10248         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:10249         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:2379          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 MASTER_IP:2379          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 MASTER_IP:2380          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8080          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::4194                 :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::10250                :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::10251                :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::10252                :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::10255                :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN     
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8472            0.0.0.0:*
```

So I assume the ports are fine?

Also etcd2 works, etcdctl `cluster-health` shows that all nodes are healthy

This is the part of cloud-config that starts the etcd2 on reboot, besides that I only store ssh keys and node username/password/groups in it:

```
#cloud-config

coreos:
  etcd2:
    name: "kubernetes-4"
    initial-advertise-peer-urls: "http://NODE_IP:2380"
    listen-peer-urls: "http://NODE_IP:2380"
    listen-client-urls: "http://NODE_IP,http://127.0.0.1:2379"
    advertise-client-urls: "http://NODE_IP:2379"
    initial-cluster-token: "etcd-cluster-1"
    initial-cluster: "kubernetes-4=http://MASTER_IP:2380,kubernetes-1=http://WORKER_1_IP:2380,kubernetes-2=http://WORKER_2_IP:2380,kubernetes-3=http://WORKER_3_IP:2380"
    initial-cluster-state: "new"
  units:
    - name: etcd2.service
      command: start
```

This is the content of `/etc/flannel/options.env` file:

```
FLANNELD_IFACE=NODE_IP
FLANNELD_ETCD_ENDPOINTS=http://MASTER_IP:2379,http://WORKER_1_IP:2379,http://WORKER_2_IP:2379,http://WORKER_3_IP:2379
```

The same endpoints are under `--etcd-servers` in `kube-apiserver.yaml` file

Any ideas/suggestion what could be the problem? Also if there are some details missing let me know, I'll add them to the post.

**Edit:** I forgot to include kube-proxy logs.

Master node kube-proxy log:

```
$ kubectl logs kube-proxy-kubernetes-4
I0615 07:47:45.250631       1 server.go:225] Using iptables Proxier.
W0615 07:47:45.286923       1 server.go:469] Failed to retrieve node info: Get http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/nodes/kubernetes-4: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: getsockopt: connection refused
W0615 07:47:45.303576       1 proxier.go:304] invalid nodeIP, initializing kube-proxy with 127.0.0.1 as nodeIP
W0615 07:47:45.303593       1 proxier.go:309] clusterCIDR not specified, unable to distinguish between internal and external traffic
I0615 07:47:45.303646       1 server.go:249] Tearing down userspace rules.
E0615 07:47:45.357276       1 reflector.go:201] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/proxy/config/api.go:49: Failed to list *api.Endpoints: Get http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/endpoints?resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: getsockopt: connection refused
E0615 07:47:45.357278       1 reflector.go:201] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/proxy/config/api.go:46: Failed to list *api.Service: Get http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/services?resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: getsockopt: connection refused
```

Worker nodes kube-proxy log:

```
$ kubectl logs kube-proxy-kubernetes-1
I0615 07:47:33.667025       1 server.go:225] Using iptables Proxier.
W0615 07:47:33.697387       1 server.go:469] Failed to retrieve node info: Get https://MASTER_IP/api/v1/nodes/kubernetes-1: dial tcp MASTER_IP:443: getsockopt: connection refused
W0615 07:47:33.712718       1 proxier.go:304] invalid nodeIP, initializing kube-proxy with 127.0.0.1 as nodeIP
W0615 07:47:33.712734       1 proxier.go:309] clusterCIDR not specified, unable to distinguish between internal and external traffic
I0615 07:47:33.712773       1 server.go:249] Tearing down userspace rules.
E0615 07:47:33.787122       1 reflector.go:201] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/proxy/config/api.go:49: Failed to list *api.Endpoints: Get https://MASTER_IP/api/v1/endpoints?resourceVersion=0: dial tcp MASTER_IP:443: getsockopt: connection refused
E0615 07:47:33.787144       1 reflector.go:201] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/proxy/config/api.go:46: Failed to list *api.Service: Get https://MASTER_IP/api/v1/services?resourceVersion=0: dial tcp MASTER_IP:443: getsockopt: connection refused
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the scripts [here](https://github.com/coreos/coreos-kubernetes)? These are the condensed versions of the tutorial you used, for various platforms. The scripts worked perfectly for me on bare metal for k8s v1.6.4. I have a [tweaked script](https://github.com/eugene-chow/kube-coreos-bash) with better encryption.

`kube-apiserver` isn't running which explains the error `dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: getsockopt: connection refused`. When I was debugging `kube-apiserver`, this was what I would do in the node:

1. Remove `/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml`.
2. Manually run a `hyperkube` container. Depending on your config, you will have to mount additional volumes (ie. `-v`) to expose files to the container. Update the image version to the one you use.

   `docker run --net=host -it -v /etc/kubernetes/ssl:/etc/kubernetes/ssl quay.io/coreos/hyperkube:v1.6.2_coreos.0`
3. The above command will launch a shell in the `hyperkube` container. Now, launch `kube-apiserver` with the flags in your `kube-apiserver.yaml` manifest. It should look similar to this example:

   `/hyperkube apiserver \
   --bind-address=0.0.0.0 \
   --etcd-cafile=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/apiserver/ca.pem \
   --etcd-certfile=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/apiserver/client.pem \
   --etcd-keyfile=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/apiserver/client-key.pem \
   --etcd-servers=https://10.246.40.20:2379,https://10.246.40.21:2379,https://10.246.40.22:2379 \
   ...`

In any case, I suggest that you tear down the cluster and try the scripts first. It might just work ootb.